# How can I get rid of excel files that I can't delete

Tags: macos, ms-office

I run OSX Lion and I have an excel spreadsheet 2011 sitting on my desktop that I regularly open, update, and save.  Whenever I open, edit, and save the excel spreadsheet, a new file is created on the desktop that I can't delete (even when excel is closed). The files have names "BEE05630", "D5A1F120", etc. I have to restart for the files to disappear from my desktop.

Any way to fix this?

Comment: How are you saving these files? are you quitting Excel before you try to delete?

Comment: Can you see hidden files in the Finder?

Comment: Try relaunching finder with the force quit dialog from the apple menu after closing excel and tell me if they disappear.

Comment: yes, i have quit excel before i try to delete them. they go away if i force quit/relaunch finder.

Comment: You definitely need to see if you have invisible files showing in the Finder. That may be your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Force quitting finder "fixes" this but is a work-around. If no one has a better fix, I'm going to have to mark this as the answer.

Press option down while right-clicking the finder in the dock, then click "Relaunch". It relaunched the desktop and the random excel file went away.

Answer (score 0):

open Terminal.app and run `rm -f "Path-To-File"`

Comment: FYI, this didn't work.

Comment: try it with sudo?

Comment: I don't know why but BestPractices method worked.  I no longer have the files to try it on.

Comment: ok. never seen the issue so my answer was kind of a stab in the dark.